# How do I turn a dataframe into a series of lists?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, series

I have had to do this several times and I'm always frustrated.  I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], ['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

print df

   A  B  C  D
a  1  2  3  4
b  5  6  7  8
```

I want to turn `df` into:

```
pd.Series([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], ['a', 'b'])

a    [1, 2, 3, 4]
b    [5, 6, 7, 8]
dtype: object
```

I've tried

```
df.apply(list, axis=1)
```

Which just gets me back the same `df`

What is a convenient/effective way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can first convert `DataFrame` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), then convert to list and last create new `Series` with index from `df` if need faster solution:

```
print (pd.Series(df.values.tolist(), index=df.index))
a    [1, 2, 3, 4]
b    [5, 6, 7, 8]
dtype: object
```

Timings with small DataFrame:

```
In [76]: %timeit (pd.Series(df.values.tolist(), index=df.index))
1000 loops, best of 3: 295 µs per loop

In [77]: %timeit pd.Series(df.T.to_dict('list'))
1000 loops, best of 3: 685 µs per loop

In [78]: %timeit df.T.apply(tuple).apply(list)
1000 loops, best of 3: 958 µs per loop
```

and with large:

```
from string import ascii_letters
letters = list(ascii_letters)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(range(10), (52 ** 2, 52)),
                  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([letters, letters]),
                  letters)

In [71]: %timeit (pd.Series(df.values.tolist(), index=df.index))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.06 ms per loop

In [72]: %timeit pd.Series(df.T.to_dict('list'))
1 loop, best of 3: 203 ms per loop

In [73]: %timeit df.T.apply(tuple).apply(list)
1 loop, best of 3: 506 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 9):

pandas tries really hard to make making dataframes convenient.  As such, it interprets lists and arrays as things you'd want to split into columns.  I'm not going to complain, this is almost always helpful.

I've done this one of two ways.

***Option 1***:

```
# Only works with a non MultiIndex
# and its slow, so don't use it
df.T.apply(tuple).apply(list)
```

***Option 2***:

```
pd.Series(df.T.to_dict('list'))
```

Both give you:

```
a    [1, 2, 3, 4]
b    [5, 6, 7, 8]
dtype: object
```

However ***Option 2*** scales better.

---

#### Timing

**given `df`**

[image]

**much larger `df`**

```
from string import ascii_letters
letters = list(ascii_letters)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(range(10), (52 ** 2, 52)),
                  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([letters, letters]),
                  letters)
```

Results for `df.T.apply(tuple).apply(list)` are erroneous because that solution doesn't work over a MultiIndex.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dataframe to list conversion

```
List_name =df_name.values.tolist()
```