# DataFrame conversion with combining multiple columns as a single array column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python. I have a pandas dataframe as follows (with 4 columns) in Python version 3.7.4:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Patient_Key': [2333836, 2319735],
                   'DX1': ["N184", 'Z6827'],
                   'DX2': ['D649', 'N184'],
                   'DX3': ['E785', 'I10']})
```

```
   Patient_Key    DX1   DX2   DX3
0      2333836   N184  D649  E785
1      2319735  Z6827  N184   I10
```

How to we convert this to a new dataframe with only 2 columns?

```
-- Expected Conversion
2333836, ["N184", "D649", "E785"]
2319735, ["Z6827", "N184", "I10"]
```

Comment: You want to convert to a column of arrays or [to a column of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38713200/1609514)?

Answer (score 4):

Filter `DX` columns and convert each row to a list with `apply`:

```
df[['Patient_Key']].join(
  df.filter(regex='DX').apply(pd.Series.tolist, 1).rename('DX')
)

   Patient_Key                  DX
0      2333836  [N184, D649, E785]
1      2319735  [Z6827, N184, I10]
```

Or convert `DX` columns sub dataframe to a list and then assign it to a columnn:

```
df['DX'] = df.filter(regex='DX').values.tolist()
df[['Patient_Key', 'DX']]

   Patient_Key                  DX
0      2333836  [N184, D649, E785]
1      2319735  [Z6827, N184, I10]
```

Comment: You can directly use `list` instead of `pd.Series.tolist`.

Comment: @Ch3steR Yep. `list` works too and is more concise here.

Comment: It could be a display issue. Do you need the column as string type or you need it to be the format when writing to csv ?

Comment: Need the column as string. Then I need to pass this to an API call.  To be precise, what we need is ["N184", "D649", "E785"]

Comment: @LCJ The actual values would be the same as need, it's just pandas dataframe when you print doesn't show quotes unless quotes are a part of string i.e something like this `' "hello world" '`

Comment: If you need it as a string, then you can `json.dumps` the list, I believe. Something like: `import json; df.filter(regex='DX').apply(lambda s: json.dumps(s.to_list()), 1)`

Comment: @LCJ Then you can try `df['DX'] = df['DX'].astype('str')` to make it a string.